# CUDA kernel only work with 1D thread index

Tags: cuda

There is a weird problem. I have following code. When I call first function it does not give correct result. However, when I call the function2 (the second function) it works fine. It is so weird to me. Does anyone has any idea about the problem? Thanks!!!

```
__global__ void function(int w, class<double> C, float *result) {  

    int r = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;  
    int c = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;  
    int half_w = w /2;  

    if (r < w && c < w) {  
        double dis = sort((double)(r - half_w) * (r - half_w) + (double)(c_half_w) * (c - half_w));  
    result[c * w + r] = (float)C.getVal(dis);  
    }  
}


__global__ void function2(int w, class<double> C, float *result) {  

    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;  

    int half_w = w /2;
    int r = tid / w;  
    int c = tid % w;    

    if (r < w && c < w) {  
        double dis = sort((double)(r - half_w) * (r - half_w) + (double)(c_half_w) * (c - half_w));  
    result[c * w + r] = (float)C.getVal(dis);  
    }  
}
```

UPDATE:
I use the `function` and `function2` to draw an image. The pixel value is based on the distance between image center and current pixel position. Based on the distance, the class C getVal will calculate the value for the pixel. So, in the kernel, I just make every thread to calculate the distance and corresponding pixel value. The correct result is compared with CPU version. The `function` is just give some random value some very larger some very small. When I changed the `result[c * w + r] = (float)C.getVal(dis)` to `result[c * w +r ] = 1.0f`, the generated image seems does not change.

The image size is W x W, to launch `function` I set 
`dim3 grid_dim(w / 64 + 1, w / 64 + 1);`
`dim3 block_dim(64, 64);`
`function<<<grid_dim, block_dim>>>(W, C, cu_img);`

To launch `function2`
`function2<<<W / 128 + 1, 128>>>(W, C, cu_img)`

Fixed:

I got the problem. I assigned too many threads to one block. The max threads in one block is 1024 in my device. Actually, when I run cuds-memcheck, I can see the `function2` does not even launched.

Comment: Can you explain what the "right answer" is ? Also how you are launching `function` and `function2` ?

Comment: Again, please add your solution as an answer. You can later accept the answer, taking the question off the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I assigned too many threads to one block. The max threads in one block is 1024 in my device. Actually, when I ran cuda-memcheck, I can see the `function2` was not ever launched.